# Aside tag not floating left when img tag is placed inside

Tags: html, css

I have my `aside` tag which floats left next to my `section` tag just fine if there is no img tag or just text inside, but other wise I cant get float left to work or inline block, nothing! I'm stumped. Does anyone know how I would fix this? It doesn't mater if I float aside left or right. it does not move with the img inside the tag

```css
  section{
  border-style: double;
  border-color: yellow;
  float:left;
}
.news-feed{
  border-style: double;
  border-color: cyan;
  float: left;
}
img{
  border-style: double;
  border-color: white;
  float: left;
}
.summary{
  border-style: double;
  border-color: purple;
  float: left;
}
aside{
  opacity: 1;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
  <section>
    <h2>Explore New Videos!</h2>
    <iframe width="700" height="397" src="LINK" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen >
    </iframe>
  </section>
  <aside>
    <div class = "news-feed">
        <img src="images/bg2.jpg" height="15%" width="5%">
        <div class = "summary">
          <p>This is text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
```

[CSS for color mapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xgep.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to apply the `width` value to both elements `section` and `aside`. Using percentage values will grant a responsive layout:

```css
 section{
  border-style: double;
  border-color: yellow;
  float:left;
  width: 70%;
}
.news-feed{
  border-style: double;
  border-color: cyan;
  float: left;
}
img{
  border-style: double;
  border-color: white;
  float: left;
}
.summary{
  border-style: double;
  border-color: purple;
  float: left;
}
aside{
  opacity: 1;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: red;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
  <section>
    <h2>Explore New Videos!</h2>
    <iframe width="700" height="397" src="https://unsplash.it/200" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen >
    </iframe>
  </section>
  <aside>
    <div class = "news-feed">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/700" height="15%" width="5%">
        <div class = "summary">
          <p>This is text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
```

Comment: Yes just a typo, sorry about that.

Comment: Not like that in my code lol, just here sorry I was not clear. I don't know what the problem is i'm out of ideas

Comment: However, then my width of me section and aside is fixed and not dependent on my content correct? wouldn't that be inefficient?

Comment: That just creates fixed sizes and content that was meant to fit those (aside and section) just becomes ugly.

Comment: Is it possible to say float left..and have that dif auto adjust to have the width of how much space is has until it bumps up against the div that is floating left before it?

Comment: The problem is [block elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements#Elements) (like `div`, `section`, `aside`...) don't fit to any `width` nor `height`unless you explicitly set them, as the [always starts on a new line and takes up the full width available](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp). They adapt to an element you may fit inside (i.e., a 400 pixels width div), but the element itself keeps taking the 100% width of the screen. You may float left, but that element in the left keeps filling all the space through the window.

Comment: So in your case you may choose not to set a width to the aside element, though the section element at least will need a width set.